# Redirect URLs with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have some old URLs in serps which are in this format:

/pneumatic-stapler-parts-438s2-p-19762.html

The important parts are the -p- (which denotes it as a product) and the number at the end which is the product_id.  We also have URLs with -c- which denotes a category.

With .htaccess, how can we redirect the old URLs to the following format:

index.php?r=product/view&id=19762

The category urls would be in this format:

index.php?r=category/view&id=123

I believe that the -p- and -c- can be used to decide which of the two formats the URL will be.

Comment: You are using some framework? Your new routes are looking like 'controller/action' pattern. Maybe you don't neew mod_rewrite then? Just write appropriate route rules for framework.

Comment: We want 301 redirects.  .htaccess is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# product
RewriteRule -p-(\d+)\.html$ /index.php?r=product/view&id=$1 [R=301,NC,QSA,L]

# category
RewriteRule -c-[\d_]*?(\d+)\.html$ /index.php?r=category/view&id=$1 [R=301,NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: This is not a redirect.  We require a 301 redirect.

Comment: This works for products:  RewriteRule -p-(\d+)\.html$ /index.php?r=product/view&id=$1 [R=301,L]  For categories the problem is that the ID of our old URLs is in this format 345_67_83 - we only want the last part, the 83.  How can we do this

Comment: here is an example category URL:  /husky-portable-air-compressor-repair-parts-c-271_458_459.html - we only want the 459 as the ID.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this all works perfectly.